# Error when using ?string("0.00") in FTL

Tags: java, freemarker

I am getting the following error when using ?string("0.00") in my FTL file as below

```
${currency}${discount?string("0.00")}
```

discount is of type BigDecimal and comes from my java code.

> 2017-02-16 10:48:08.481 [http-nio-80-exec-3] ERROR freemarker.runtime - Template processing error: "Expected method. discount?string evaluated instead to freemarker.template.SimpleScalar on line 56, column 154 in WEB-INF/views/abc/abc-result.ftl."
>   freemarker.template.TemplateException: Expected method. discount?string evaluated instead to freemarker.template.SimpleScalar on line 56, column 154 in WEB-INF/views/abc/abc-result.ftl.
>       at freemarker.core.TemplateObject.invalidTypeException(TemplateObject.java:136) ~[freemarker-2.3.19.jar:2.3.19]
>       at freemarker.core.MethodCall._getAsTemplateModel(MethodCall.java:114) ~[freemarker-2.3.19.jar:2.3.19]
>       at freemarker.core.Expression.getAsTemplateModel(Expression.java:89) ~[freemarker-2.3.19.jar:2.3.19]
>       at freemarker.core.Expression.getStringValue(Expression.java:93) ~[freemarker-2.3.19.jar:2.3.19]

Comment: And which is the type of `discount`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant type of discount is BigDecimal :)

Comment: I happen to fix it. I changed it to ${currency}${discount?number?string("0.00")} I am passing BigDecimal from java side but not sure as to why I need to convert to number again

Comment: @Arjun Vinod post it as an answer so future readers can find the solution easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I happen to fix it. I changed it to ${currency}${discount?number?string("0.00")} I am passing BigDecimal from java side but not sure as to why I need to convert to number again